# Does Weierstrass approximation theorem have any application to differential equations?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Weierstrass approximation theorem states that continuous periodic functions can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials. I wonder if it has any applications in differential equations, where you can approximate a solution by approximating a function, and then prove rigorously that it does converge to a real solution. I would be very grateful if you could give me some references.

Comment: Could you clarify to what extent you want to read about this, for example why looking up "Weierstrass" in the index of a few undergraduate level PDE texts (separation of variables followed by solutions as expansions in a series of the eigenfunctions) doesn't give what you want. For example, [Weinberger's well known book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/048668640X) (although here you want to look up "uniform convergence" in the index).

Comment: That's one of the things I want to do in my research. Predecessors have given the case of finite trigonometric polynomials for differential equations, so for general continuous periodic functions, I want to use the approximation theorem for uniform approximation, trying to prove that the approximate solution is indeed close to the real solution under some spatial norm. Of course, this is just an idea, so far I have not personally found anyone who has used similar methods, so I would like to seek some help. Thank you!

Comment: I'm working on dynamical systems, and the specific problem doesn't seem to have much to do with eigenvalues. Fourier expansion alone doesn't seem to really help. So I want to use the Weierstrass approximation theorem for uniform approximation. I would be very grateful if you could give me some references in this regard!

Comment: *Predecessors have given the case of finite trigonometric polynomials for differential equations* --- It would probably help to specify what the predecessors are (published papers, books, etc.), because I'm not sure whether you're simply asking something basic about Fourier series or some specialized topic that I don't recognize. If specialized, I probably don't know anything about it, but I do have a lot of "general awareness" of mathematical fields, personal references, and experience in looking things up (print and online).

Comment: Consider the differential equation $ dx/dt=f(x(t)), x(0)=a $. It has been shown that the solution has some good properties when F is a trigonometric polynomial. I want to generalize this to periodic functions, and there are two possible methods: Fourier expansion approximation, and trigonometric polynomial uniform approximation. I was more curious to see if the latter could solve the problem, so I wanted to see if any mathematicians had used a similar approach. Thank you!

Comment: Since the paper I read has a confidentiality agreement, it has not been made public, so I cannot provide specific details. Sorry!

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be continuous with period $2\pi.$ For $ n\ge 0$ let $C_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n(A_j\cos jx+B_j\sin jx)$ be the $n$th partial sum of the Fourier series for $f. $ Theorem  (Fejer):$\frac {1}{m+1}\sum_{n=0}^mC_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ as $m\to\infty.$

Comment: What I want is the application of the consistent approximation theorem in differential equations, thank you!

Comment: Without specifics or context it's hard to know what sort of answer you want/expect. Also, this site is not really set up to deal with semi-confidential material...

Comment: This is just an interesting idea, not just for research. I would appreciate it if you know some applications of trigonometric function uniform approximation in equations and tell me. Because the approximation of trigonometric functions I have seen in the field of differential equations is in the form of Fourier series, almost all of which prove a certain uniform convergence through iteration. However, I have not seen the precedent of applying trigonometric function uniform approximation theorem directly, which must be an interesting means.